# Inserting characters in spaces in list of strings

Tags: python, string, append, bioinformatics

I'm trying to append a list of strings by adding "->" and ":" between the spaces in each line. My current output looks like this:

```
0 1 A
1 2 T
2 3 A
3 4 G
4 5 A
2 6 C
0 7 G
7 8 A
8 9 T
```

But I would like for it to look like:

```
0->1:A
1->2:T
2->3:A
3->4:G
4->5:A
2->6:C
0->7:G
7->8:A
8->9:T
```

You can find the code I'm using below.

```
def trie_edges(patterns):
    myTrie = trieConstruction(patterns)
    sortMatrix = lambda item: ' '.join(map(str,item[0]))+' '+item[1]
    return map(sortMatrix, myTrie.edges.items())

def main():

    with open('C:/Users/Sami/PycharmProjects/Bioinformatics/rosalind_ba2d.txt') as input_data:
    patterns = [line.strip() for line in input_data.readlines()]
    createMatrix = trie_edges(patterns)
    print ('\n'.join(createMatrix))
```

Comment: what's wrong with `sortMatrix = lambda item: '->'.join(map(str,item[0]))+':'+item[1]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

your `sortMatrix` lambda function creates that format

```
sortMatrix = lambda item: ' '.join(map(str,item[0]))+' '+item[1]
```

it inserts spaces between all items.

I'd do that instead:

```
sortMatrix = lambda item: '->'.join(map(str,item[0]))+':'+item[1]
```

so 2 first terms are separated by `->` and the other with `:`

maybe nicer using `format` and dropping `join` since it's overkill for 2 elements (and that saves the `map(str` thing:

```
sortMatrix = lambda item: "{}->{}:{}".format(item[0][0],item[0][1],item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the inner `re.sub` substitutes the first blank in each line and passes its result to the outer `re.sub` which substitutes the second blank in each line.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> source = StringIO('''\
... 0 1 A
... 1 2 T
... 2 3 A
... 3 4 G
... 4 5 A
... 2 6 G''')
>>> import re
>>> for line in source.readlines():
...     re.sub(' ', ':', re.sub(' ','->',line.strip(),1))
... 
'0->1:A'
'1->2:T'
'2->3:A'
'3->4:G'
'4->5:A'
'2->6:G'
```